# Golang cookies has empty timestamp

Tags: go, cookies, timestamp

I'm wirting a go programm that needs to login to a website to get some data. The login process is done, but now i have the problem that i don't get access to the protected page with the cookie i got from the login form. After examing them and comparing to the ones my browser gets, i noticed that my program gets cookies with "empty" timestamps. Can someone point out, how i get the cookie with a correct timestamp? That would be fantastic.

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var CookieJar *cookiejar.Jar
var httpClient *http.Client

func dbgPrintCurCookies(CurCookies []*http.Cookie) {
    var cookieNum int = len(CurCookies)
    log.Printf("cookieNum=%d", cookieNum)
    for i := 0; i < cookieNum; i++ {
        var curCk *http.Cookie = CurCookies[i]
        //log.Printf("curCk.Raw=%s", curCk.Raw)
        log.Printf("Cookie [%d]", i)
        log.Printf("Name\t=%s", curCk.Name)
        log.Printf("Value\t=%s", curCk.Value)
        log.Printf("Path\t=%s", curCk.Path)
        log.Printf("Domain\t=%s", curCk.Domain)
        log.Printf("Expires\t=%s", curCk.Expires)
        log.Printf("RawExpires=%s", curCk.RawExpires)
        log.Printf("MaxAge\t=%d", curCk.MaxAge)
        log.Printf("Secure\t=%t", curCk.Secure)
        log.Printf("HttpOnly=%t", curCk.HttpOnly)
        log.Printf("Raw\t=%s", curCk.Raw)
        log.Printf("Unparsed=%s", curCk.Unparsed)
    }
}

func main() {
    CookieJar, _ = cookiejar.New(nil)

    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Jar:     CookieJar,
        Timeout: 10 * time.Second,
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        }}

    LSFRedirURL := ""
    pw := "
    us := ""
    LoginURL := "login website ?j_password=" + pw + "&j_username=" + us
    GetFinalCookieURL := ""



    //get first cookie
    nextURL := LSFRedirURL
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        resp, _ := httpClient.Get(nextURL)
        // fmt.Println("StatusCode:", resp.StatusCode)
        // fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)
        if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
            // fmt.Println("Done!")
            break
        } else {
            nextURL = resp.Header.Get("Location")
        }
    }

    //safe first cookie
    url1, _ := url.Parse("first cookie website")
    firstCookie := CookieJar.Cookies(url1)[0]
    fmt.Println("First Cookie :\\)")

    //getting second cookie and params
    // var cam []string
    var resp *http.Response
    nextURL = LoginURL
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        resp, _ = httpClient.Post(nextURL, "", nil)
        // fmt.Println("StatusCode:", resp.StatusCode)
        // fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)
        // cam = append(cam, nextURL)
        if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
            fmt.Println("Done!")
            break
        } else {
            nextURL = resp.Header.Get("Location")
        }
    }

    //second cookie
    url2, _ := url.Parse("website second cookie is from")
    secondCookie := CookieJar.Cookies(url2)[0]
    fmt.Println("Second Cookie :\\)")

    //params
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    c, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    data := html.UnescapeString(string(c))
    //fmt.Println(data)
    getvalue := regexp.MustCompile("value=\".*\"")
    values := getvalue.FindAllStringSubmatch(data, -1)
    values[0][0] = strings.TrimSuffix(values[0][0], "\"")
    values[0][0] = strings.TrimPrefix(values[0][0], "value=\"")
    values[1][0] = strings.TrimSuffix(values[1][0], "\"")
    values[1][0] = strings.TrimPrefix(values[1][0], "value=\"")

    v := url.Values{
        "SAMLResponse": {values[1][0]},
        "RelayState":   {values[0][0]},
    }

    body := strings.NewReader(v.Encode())

    fmt.Println("Values :\\)")

    //adding values and cookies to request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", GetFinalCookieURL, body)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.AddCookie(firstCookie)
    req.AddCookie(secondCookie)
    resp, _ = httpClient.Do(req)

    //we got the real cookie
    url3, _ := url.Parse("website i get the cookies for")
    dbgPrintCurCookies(CookieJar.Cookies(url3))
    finalCookie := CookieJar.Cookies(url3)[0]
    finalCookie2 := CookieJar.Cookies(url3)[1]



    fmt.Println("StatusCode:", resp.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)
    nextURL = resp.Header.Get("Location")
    fmt.Println(nextURL)

    nextURL = "website i need the cookies for"

    req, _ = http.NewRequest("GET", nextURL, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.AddCookie(finalCookie)
    req.AddCookie(finalCookie2)
    resp, _ = httpClient.Do(req)
    url3, _ = url.Parse("final cookie website")
    dbgPrintCurCookies(CookieJar.Cookies(url3))
    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    data3, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(data3))

}
```

And this is an example of what the cookie i get looks like:

```
2018/02/10 01:55:48 cookieNum=2
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Cookie [0]
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Name    =JSESSIONID
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Value   =86E2C361905167A1F64FC45C400649F2.stupo1
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Path    =
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Domain  =
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Expires =0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2018/02/10 01:55:48 RawExpires=
2018/02/10 01:55:48 MaxAge  =0
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Secure  =false
2018/02/10 01:55:48 HttpOnly=false
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Raw =
2018/02/10 01:55:48 Unparsed=[]
```

Edit: Added the complete code. And this is the cookie in the Browser:
[Cookie in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA4yR.png)

Comment: Please include `firstCookie` and `secondCookie`'s definitions and any related code. You probably forgot to set the expires attribute (it's optional as without one it is called a *session cookie* where it is deleted when the browser is closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies come in two flavors: The once you receive in a `Set-Cookie` header and the ones you send in a `Cookie` header. Only `Set-Cookie` header cookies have expiration times and various fields while `Cookie` header type cookies are plain name,value tuples. and that's what a cookiejar returns because that's what included in the Cookie header.

The default cookie jar implementation of the stdlib does not provide a mechanism to extract all cookies or fields other than name and value. If you need that information use any other open source cookie jar implementation.

(Note that the whole purpose of the stdlib cookie jar implementation is to transparently handle cookies, even through redirections. It is not a solution to collect information about incomming Set-Cookie header and the various values sent in them.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)